# KVM port forwarding (Ubunto 20.04)

Tags: kvm, port-forwarding, ufw

I have a fresh installation of my computer of `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`.

I have installed kvm:

`sudo apt -y install bridge-utils cpu-checker libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon qemu qemu-kvm`

I have created a new VM using virt-manager, named 'ubuntu20.04'.

```
 Id   Name          State
-----------------------------
 7    ubuntu20.04   running
```

which is working fine. It has the default networking settings:

```
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes
```

I have edited the net file to set a fixed ip address for the VM using:

`> virsh net-edit default`

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>57bd2ef8-5ef9-405e-b631-efdd10a12ca8</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:7c:ae:96'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:21:02:54' name='ubuntu20.04' ip='192.168.122.101'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I can ssh the virtual machine without any issue: `ssh 192.168.122.101`

My host machine has public IP 192.168.1.85.

```
ifconfig
enp3s0f0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.85  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::9e0a:64e6:7542:cdc4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:4d:e9:d4:35:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 306030  bytes 451106893 (451.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 3303  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19624  bytes 2100797 (2.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1792  bytes 176567 (176.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1792  bytes 176567 (176.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:7c:ae:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13458  bytes 837489 (837.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68353  bytes 428375346 (428.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe21:254  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:21:02:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 152  bytes 15868 (15.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 718  bytes 44209 (44.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**GOAL:** My objective now is to access the ssh of the VM from other machines in my local network. I want to do this by redirecting any traffic coming to the main machine at port 2222 (192.168.1.85: 2222) to the vm (192.168.122.101:22).

I have (as default after the Ubuntu installation):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

I have tried to follow the instructions found on several sites, but without success.
For example, I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kvm-forward-ports-to-guests-vm-with-ufw-on-linux/), because it is based on using UFW, which is by default active in ubuntu. Basically the method is based on:

1. adding a hook file (qemu) in:

> /etc/libvirt/hooks/qemu

containing the following:

```
v=$(/sbin/iptables -L FORWARD -n -v | /usr/bin/grep 192.168.122.0/24 | /usr/bin/wc -l)
# avoid duplicate as this hook get called for each VM
#[ $v -le 2 ] && 

if [ $v -le 2]
then
        /sbin/iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o virbr0 -m state -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 192.168.122.0/24 --state N>
fi
```

2. and editing the file

> **/etc/ufw/before.rules**

adding (at the top) the following:

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.85 -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.101:22 -m comment --comment "VM2/OpenBSD SSH port forwarding"
COMMIT
```

At the end, following these instructions, I have the following iptables:

```
sudo iptables-save -t nat
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sat Jan 29 16:20:08 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [268:56889]
:INPUT ACCEPT [129:22767]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1213:187394]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1213:187394]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.85/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -m comment --comment "VM2/OpenBSD SSH port forwarding" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.101:22
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.85/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -m comment --comment "VM2/OpenBSD SSH port forwarding" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.101:22
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.85/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -m comment --comment "VM2/OpenBSD SSH port forwarding" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.101:22
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.85/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -m comment --comment "VM2/OpenBSD SSH port forwarding" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.101:22
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

which seems compatible with those obtained in the tutorial.
However, when I try to login to the VM-shh using the forwarded port, I get an error, as follows:

```
ssh 192.168.1.85 -p 2222
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.85 port 2222: Connection refused
```

Thank you in advance for any help!